# How to make this column times row operation with pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question related to matrix operations in pandas, here is what I would like to achieve.

I have a pandas data frame with each row corresponding to the quantities of ingredient contained in a recipe.
[ingredients_contained_in_recipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2ymo.png)

And a second data frame containing the nutrients data for each ingredient.
[nutrients_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwXlc.png)

I would like to obtain a new data frame with each row corresponding to the sum of nutrients contained in the ingredients * quantities of a recipe.

Sorry if I haven't been clear enough, that's the first time I am posting here.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dot product here to solve this most efficiently. If you're not familiar with linear algebra: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product. I'll explain and then my implementation is below.

You have a dataframe your dataframe of the quantities of ingredients in each recipe, let's call it `quantities_df`. In a row, you have each cell corresponding to one ingredient. Let's say you have `n` ingredients. A short sample of yours:

|  | carotte | beurre doux | muscade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 125 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 35 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 125 | 0 |

Now, you have your second dataframe that has the nutrients for each ingredient, call this `nutrients_df`. Each cell of this dataframe corresponds to the amount of a nutrient in just one of the ingredients. We have `n` rows, one corresponding to each ingredient. Again, a short sample:

|  | nrj_kcal | proteines_g | glucides_g | lipides_g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| carotte | 40.2 | 0.63 | 7.59 | 0.5 |
| beurre doux | 741 | 0.7 | 0.99 | 81.5 |
| muscade | 504 | 5.3 | 28.5 | 36.3 |

Let's take the dot product of one recipe by one column. We have:

`1 * 40.2 + 125 * 741 + 3 * 504 = 94177.2`

In other words, you have the total sum of the product of each ingredient by it's nutrients. If you take the dot product for every row by every column, i.e. the matrix product, you get the intended result.

Here is my implementation:

Assuming you already have `quantities_df` and `nutrients_df`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

recipe_nutrients = pd.DataFrame(
                       data=np.dot(quantities_df.values, nutrients_df.values),
                       columns=nutrients_df.columns
                   )
```

This looks as expected:

|  | nrj_kcal | proteines_g | glucides_g | lipides_g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 94177.2 | 104.03 | 216.84 | 10296.9 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 25935 | 24.5 | 34.65 | 2852.5 |
| 3 | 92625 | 87.5 | 123.75 | 10187.5 |

Comment: Thanks Branden,
Your asnwer was very clear and I learnt a new way of seeing this problem and combining dataframes!